# Apache web server multiple project folder hosting issue

Tags: apache

I have configured `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` as follows .

```
  ServerName 0.0.0.0
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost        
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html       

    WSGIDaemonProcess python-app threads=15 maximum-requests=10000
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myapp/myapp.wsgi
    
    WSGIProcessGroup python-app



    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/myapp>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/test"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/test">
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Now my project folder structure is like :

[image]

I am able to access `myapp` (python flask project) . But not my `test`  project `html` files. Looks like the `myapp.wsgi` (via flask app) is managing all the `urls` . url like `test\index.html` (to access test project) is not configured in flask app and hence getting error.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after updating `WSGIScriptAlias` `/api /var/www/html/myapp/myapp.wsgi`. Need to call `apis` with `/api` in-front

Initially it was `WSGIScriptAlias` `/ /var/www/html/myapp/myapp.wsgi` overriding all url mappings.